# how to fetch database table using drupal custom module

Tags: php, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I tried to develop a custom module, which having two date pop-up "start_date" and "end_date",i have database table which contain Id,name,paid date,paid amount .i need to fetch database and display as table on button click.i wrote some code in drupal ,please correct if wrong and please guide me to fetch the table for particular date range
[form design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdkKT.png)

**my codings:**

**Uniview8PastpaymentsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\uniview8_pastpayments\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\uniview8_pastpayments\Uniview8PastPaymentsStorage;

class Uniview8PastpaymentsController extends ControllerBase {
  public function entryList() {
    $content = array();

    $content['message'] = array(
      '#markup' => $this->t('Pastpayment history for selected date ranges.'),
    );

    $rows = array();
    $headers = array(t('Id'), t('Name'), t('Paid Date'), t('Paid Amount'));

    foreach ($entries = Uniview8PastPaymentsStorage::load() as $entry) {
      $rows[] = array_map('Drupal\Component\Utility\SafeMarkup::checkPlain', (array) $entry);
    }
    $content['table'] = array(
      '#type' => 'table',
      '#header' => $headers,
      '#rows' => $rows,
      '#empty' => t('No entries available.'),
    );
    $content['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;

    return $content;
  }
}
```

**Form**
uniview8_pastpayments.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\uniview8_pastpayments\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class uniview8_pastpayments extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'uniview8_pastpayments';
  }

 public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

 $form['set_start_date'] = [
      '#title' => $this->t('START DATE '),
      '#type' => 'date',
      '#attributes' => array('type'=> 'date', 'min'=> '-12 months', 'max' => 'now' ),
      '#date_date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
    ];


 $form['set_end_date'] = [
      '#title' => $this->t('END DATE'),
      '#type' => 'date',
      '#attributes' => array('type'=> 'date', 'min'=> '-12 months', 'max' => 'now' ),
      '#date_date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
    ];


  $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Fetch'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
    );
    return $form;


}

}
```

> how i can fetch the database using submit button

```
**DB_select Function
Uniview8PastPaymentsStorage.php**
<?php
namespace Drupal\uniview8_pastpayments;
class Uniview8PastPaymentsStorage {

  public static function load($entry = array()) {

    $select = db_select('pastpayments', 'example');
    $select->fields('example')
    $select->condition('paiddate',$entry['set_start_date'], '>=')
    $select->condition('paiddate',$entry['set_end_date'], '>=')
    $select->execute();

    foreach ($entry as $field => $value) {
      $select->condition($field, $value);
    }
    // Return the result in object format.
    return $select->execute()->fetchAll();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your form is display at your controller page then you have to use ajax in your form submit
like this

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\uniview8_pastpayments\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ChangedCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CssCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand;


class uniview8_pastpayments extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'uniview8_pastpayments';
  }

 public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

 $form['set_start_date'] = [
      '#title' => $this->t('START DATE '),
      '#type' => 'date',
      '#attributes' => array('type'=> 'date', 'min'=> '-12 months', 'max' => 'now' ),
      '#date_date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
    ];


 $form['set_end_date'] = [
      '#title' => $this->t('END DATE'),
      '#type' => 'date',
      '#attributes' => array('type'=> 'date', 'min'=> '-12 months', 'max' => 'now' ),
      '#date_date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
    ];


  $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Fetch'),
      '#ajax' => [
          //'callback' => 'Drupal\mcal_textmining\Form\CreateReportsForm::submitCreateReport',
          'callback' => array($this, 'fetchResult'),
          'event' => 'click',
          'progress' => array(
              'type' => 'throbber',
              'message' => t('Submitting...')
          )
      ]
    );
    return $form;


}
 /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function fetchResult(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
     $maxDate = $form_state->getValue('set_start_date');
     $minDate = $form_state->getValue('set_end_date');
     $connection = Database::getConnection();
     $single = $connection->select('pastpayments', 'x')
        ->fields('x', array('Id','name','paiddate','paidamount'))
        ->condition('paiddate', $maxDate, "<=")
        ->condition('paiddate', $minDate, ">=");
     $executed = $single->execute();
     $results = $executed->fetchAssoc();
     foreach($results as $result){
       /*
          creat html table's tbody with result
          like
          $tbody .= "<tr><td>paidamount</td></tr>" 
      */

     }
     // now append the result into the table as tbody
     // with drupal ajax 
     $response = new AjaxResponse();
     $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('tbodyID', $tbody));
     return $response;

  }
}
```

but if your form is at another page and after submit form redirect user to your controller page then send startdate and enddate as argument to the controller and then make database query from your controller

and then append the result into the page 
thanks